# C++ Read Value from a pointer to struct including the target struct in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I am new to c++ and trying to make an atm. It consits of one file reading user data from files and a main file. Everytime I try to read the output of the returned pointer to the array of structs, where the data is stored, I get strange data. I think there is a problem when assigning strings to the first struct, because when I tried with test values (third file) it worked.

Edit:
I can read out integeres from the strcut, but I have problems with strings.

Here is the code

users.cpp (Creates the struct, included in main.cpp)

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define STRING_ERROR 4294967295
#define MAX_USERS 100000
using namespace std;

struct user
{
    int id;
    string firstname;
    string name;
    int age;
    int pin;
};
struct user_container{
    int size;
    user users [MAX_USERS];
};

typedef struct user User;
typedef struct user_container container;


void print_user_vars(User *user){
    cout << "Id: " << user->id << "\nFirstname: " << user->firstname << "\nName: " << user->name << "\nAge: " << user->age << "\nPIN: " << user->pin << endl;
}

int get_usercount(string path){
    int usercount = 0;
    ifstream file;
    string line;
    file.open(path, ios::binary | ios::in);
    while(true){
        getline(file , line);
        if(file.fail())
            break;
        if(line.find("}") != STRING_ERROR){
            usercount++;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return usercount;
}

container * get_users(string path){
    const int usercount = get_usercount(path);
    ifstream file;
    string line;
    User users[usercount];
    const char *values[5] = {"id", "firstname", "name", "age", "pin"};

    file.open(path, ios::binary | ios::in);
    User proto_user;
    int user_num = 0;
    while(true){
        getline(file , line);
        if(file.fail())
            break;
        if(line.find(":") != STRING_ERROR){
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                if(line.find(values[i]) != STRING_ERROR){
                    string value;
                    for(int v = 0; v < line.length(); v++){
                        if(v > line.find_first_of(":")){
                            value += line[v];
                        }
                    }
                    if(values[i] == "id"){
                        proto_user.id = stoi(value);
                    }
                    else if(values[i] == "firstname"){
                        proto_user.firstname = value;
                    }
                    else if(values[i] == "name"){
                        proto_user.name = value;
                    }
                    else if(values[i] == "age"){
                        proto_user.age = stoi(value);
                    }
                    else if(values[i] == "pin"){
                        proto_user.pin = stoi(value);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(line.find("}") != STRING_ERROR){
            //print_user_vars(&proto_user);
            users[user_num++] = proto_user;
            //cout << "Added user at " << user_num << endl;
        }
        //cout << line << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < user_num; i++){
        //cout << "\nUSER: " << i + 1 << endl;
        //print_user_vars(&users[i]);
    }

    static container con;
    con.size = usercount;
    for(int i = 0; i < usercount; i++){
        if(i <= MAX_USERS){
            // con.users[i] = users[i] didnt work, but this does
            con.users[i].firstname = users[i].firstname;
            con.users[i].age = users[i].age;
            con.users[i].name = users[i].name;
            con.users[i].pin = users[i].pin;
            con.users[i].id = users[i].id;
        }
    }
    print_user_vars(&con.users[0]);

    return &con;
}
```

main.cpp (Calls the function)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "includes/users.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    string wasd = "w";
    int id;
    int pin;
    cout << "\n    Welcome\n\n    ID\n>>> ";
    cin >> id;
    cout << "    PIN\n>>> ";
    cin >> pin;
    container *con = get_users("users");
    int size = con->size;
    cout << "Age: " << con->users[0].age << ", PIN: " << con->users[0].pin << ", Firstname: " << con->users[0].firstname << ", Name: "
    << con->users[0].name << ", ID: " << con->users[0].id << endl;  

    //Functionality

    return 0;
}
```

Simpler.cpp (Just like users.cpp, but with test values, included in main.cpp)

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define STRING_ERROR 4294967295
#define MAX_USERS 100000
using namespace std;

struct user
{
    int id;
    string firstname;
    string name;
    int age;
    int pin;
};
struct user_container{
    int size;
    user users [MAX_USERS];
};

typedef struct user User;
typedef struct user_container container;

container * get_users(string path){
    const int usercount = 2;
    User users[usercount];

    users[0].age = 59;
    users[0].firstname = "Peter";
    users[0].name = "Bremer";
    users[0].id = 456878;
    users[0].pin = 1234;

    users[1].age = 8;
    users[1].firstname = "a";
    users[1].name = "b";
    users[1].id = 456;
    users[1].pin = 1111;


    static container con;
    con.size = usercount;
    for(int i = 0; i < usercount; i++){
        if(i <= MAX_USERS){
            // con.users[i] = users[i] didnt work, but this does
            con.users[i].firstname = users[i].firstname;
            con.users[i].age = users[i].age;
            con.users[i].name = users[i].name;
            con.users[i].pin = users[i].pin;
            con.users[i].id = users[i].id;
        }
    }
    cout << "Usercount " << usercount << endl;
    return &con;
}

int main(void){
    container *con = get_users("users");
    int size = con->size;
    cout << "Age: " << con->users[0].age << ", PIN: " << con->users[0].pin << ", Firstname: " << con->users[0].firstname << ", Name: "
    << con->users[0].name << ", ID: " << con->users[0].id << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in *get_users* you compare string being `char*` using == which is wrong, use *strcmp* or use at least one `std::string`

Comment: or course I speak about the first version of the function, because == return an unspecified result which can be always false you may never initialize the fields of *proto_user* so they have an undefined value when you use them. Use `std::string values[5]` rather than `const char * values[5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the answer you are looking for:

Avoid using `typedef` when you don't need it. Just name your struct `User`, it will be available under that name without writing `struct User`.

And for your container, just use one of the STL containers. `std::vector<User>` would be a good start. This also removes the need for `MAX_USERS`.

```cpp
struct User
{
   int id;
   std::string firstname;
   std::string name;
   int age;
   int pin;
};

typedef std::vector<User> container;
```

With the three interfaces in `user.cpp` you can now just use

```cpp
void print_user_vars(const User& user);
int get_usercount(const std::string& path);
container get_users(const std::string& path);
```

and thus get rid of the `static container con;` in `get_users`.
With a `std::vector` I no longer see a need for the `get_usercount` function.

And instead of macros go for constants (and remove magic numbers):

```cpp
auto const STRING_ERROR = std::string::npos;
```

(Though I don't agree with the name `STRING_ERROR`. It's more a `STRING_NOT_FOUND`.)

Cleanup of `print_user_vars` after signature change:

```cpp
void print_user_vars(const User& user)
{
   std::cout << "Id: " << user.id << "\nFirstname: " << user.firstname
             << "\nName: " << user.name << "\nAge: " << user.age
             << "\nPIN: " << user.pin << std::endl;
}
```

And getting some inspiration from `get_usercount` (a method I don't believe you need):

```cpp
int get_usercount(const std::string& path)
{
   int usercount = 0;
   std::ifstream file(path, std::ios_base::binary);
   std::string line;
   while(std::getline(file, line))
   {
      if(line.find("}") != STRING_ERROR)
      {
         usercount++;
      }
   }
   return usercount;
}
```

This line in `get_users` is NOT C++. (It's part of the C99 standard):

```cpp
   User users[usercount];
```

And as @bruno points out:

```cpp
else if(values[i] == "name"){
```

does not work. Consider

```cpp
else if(std::strcmp(values[i], "name") == 0){
```

Comment: It finally worked with the vector and a const iterator. Thank you.